# Cannot view commited css files in GitHub Repository

Tags: css, git, github

I recently started using Git.
I am using Git to version control a wordpress theme development.

I committed many .css, .png and font files in my Git repository and pushed it to 'origin'.
However I cannot view the entire css, images and font folder in my repository.
But files are found when I run and exists command.

Please tell me if there is a setting that I'm missing.

**EDIT**
Sorry I didn't mention that I AM using Sourcetree. And I working on a branch and not the master. I have committed the changes to my branch. So there are no unstaged files. Yet I cannot see the mentioned files in the Github page for that Branch. Is there a separate step to push changes to the branch to remote location?

Comment: Can you show `git status` command output?

Comment: using git gui ,bitbucket or else ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of steps to get local files pushed to a git repository. Firstly, make sure you are in a git initialized directory, and that you have a current copy of whatever branch you plan on pushing to with `git pull`. When you are done making a change you can add it to the list of changes to be committed with `git add`. From there you can commit with `git commit`. After that it should be as simple as pushing to your branch (which is probably master). That looks like `git push -u origin master`. Hope this helps, but if it doesn't would you mind detailing exactly what steps you are taking so that we can work through where the problem is?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I am using Sourcetree as the GUI. Working on a branch and committing changes to the branch. But can't view the mentioned files on the github page for that branch

Answer (score 0):

To be clear: You say that the files are there when you run. Do you mean when you are running the site locally on your own PC?

It sounds like you are either not: adding them, committing them or pushing them. An alternative is if they are in folders specified in your .gitignore file but at this point that sounds unlikely.

While using the command line tools is nice it might be helpful to use a GUI based tool until you get the hang of it - I would recommend downloading sourcetree, choose open and select the folder that contains your project and git. Once in there you will be able to see any unstaged files pretty easily - these are the files that are either not added or ones that have changes that are not commited.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that I AM using Sourcetree. And I working on a branch and not the master. I have committed the changes to my branch. So there are no unstaged files. Yet I cannot see the mentioned files in the Github page for that Branch. Is there a separate step to push changes to the branch to remote location?